# Android can't add search button to options menu

Tags: java, android

I am following this [Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html) but I can't get a simple search button to show up on the options menu.
Code:

**main_activity_actions.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          android:showAsAction="never" /> </menu>
```

**Added this to MainActivity.java**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }
```

App loads OK but no icons show up, I have downloaded standard icons and placed them in each of the drawable folders. Any ideas why is it not working?

Not sure if related but the tutorial states

"The icon attribute requires a resource ID for an image. The name that follows @drawable/ must be the name of a bitmap image you've saved in your project's res/drawable/ directory. For example, "@drawable/ic_action_search" refers to ic_action_search.png."

But I didn't have folder res/drawable/ just res/drawable-hdpi, res/drawable-ldpi ...
Shold I create another folder res/drawable/ if so which icon should go in it (the official icon set I downloaded had all the res/drawable-hdpi ones but no res/drawable/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just Replace your code with mine and it will work for you.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        tools:context="com.example.actionbar.MainActivity" >
         <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
              android:title="@string/action_search"
              app:showAsAction="always"/>


          <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
              android:title="@string/action_settings"
              app:showAsAction="never"/>



    </menu>
```

Comment: You only changed app:showAsAction="always" the tutorial says "ifroom" I tried it in lanscape mode also and it didn't show with "ifroom" why does it not work?

Comment: see the lines after 1st line in menu tag.

Comment: not working for me on galaxy s8 android 8.0 with androidx.

Answer (score 1):

One key Note - XML file names shouldn't have Capital letters, in your case, it shows 'Main_activity_blah...' Keep that in mind. You've 'Main_activity.....' with you and you are calling 'main_activity....' in your code...

Please check that...and comment back.

Comment: Good point but the actual file was lower case, going to also check png file names of icons

Comment: Files all lower case :( I have edited the post above with something that might be related. last two paragraphs