# Action bar items appear only in the overflow

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar

**activity_main_actions.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/actions_search"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/actions_share"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/actions_settings"/>

</menu>
```

**Main_Activity.java**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

I am trying to get both the **Search** and **Share** icons to be shown on the action bar and the **Settings** to be in the overflow but this is what I get

[image]

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23425099/android-cant-add-search-button-to-options-menu/23425558#23425558

Answer (score 0):

it worked, i replaced

android:showAsAction="always"
with
app:showAsAction="always"